# Deleting data with multiple referential integrities

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have 3 tables:

```
Meeting_t : Meeting_id (PK), create_date (Date)
Prog_call : prog_call_id (PK) and Meeting_id (FK)
Lock_t    : lock_id (PK) and prog_call_id (FK)
```

There could be multiple records corresponding to each Meeting_id in Prog_call and similarly multiple records in Lock_t corresponding to each prog_call_id.

Now I want to create a procedure which deletes all the records with create_date < first day of previous year. This should also delete the corresponding data from other 2 tables (Prog_call and Lock_t).

I created the following prodecure to do the task:

```
PROCEDURE CleanBefore(delete_before DATE)
IS
  meeting_id_v           dev.prog_call.meeting_id%TYPE;
  prog_call_id_v         dev.prog_call.prog_call_id%TYPE;

  CURSOR meeting_c IS
    SELECT st.meeting_id
    FROM dev.meeting_t st
    WHERE TRUNC(st.logoff_datum) <= TRUNC(CleanBefore.delete_before);

  CURSOR prog_call_c IS
    SELECT pa.prog_call_id
    FROM dev.prog_call pa
    WHERE pa.meeting_id = meeting_id_v;

BEGIN
  OPEN meeting_c;
    LOOP
      FETCH meeting_c INTO meeting_id_v;
        OPEN prog_call_c;
          LOOP
            FETCH prog_call_c INTO prog_call_id_v;

            DELETE FROM dev.lock_t lt
            WHERE lt.prog_call_id = prog_call_id_v;

            DELETE FROM dev.prog_call pa
            WHERE pa.prog_call_id = prog_call_id_v;
          END LOOP;
        CLOSE prog_call_c;

        DELETE FROM dev.meeting_t st
        WHERE st.meeting_id = meeting_id_v;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE meeting_c;
END CleanBefore;
```

So far it is looking good to me.. I have compiled it and testing is in Progress. However I always look for a better solution. And i believe here is also a probability of making it more optimized. Any Suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could three straight deletes e.g.

```
PROCEDURE cleanBefore( delete_before DATE )
IS

  DELETE FROM lock_t l
  WHERE l.prog_call_id IN
    (SELECT p.prog_call_id
     FROM meeting_t m
          INNER JOIN prog_call p
            ON (p.meeting_id = m.meeting_id)
     WHERE trunc(m.logoff_datum) <= trunc(cleanBefore.delete_before);

  DELETE FROM prog_call p
  WHERE p.meeting_id IN
    (SELECT m.meeting_id
     FROM meeting_t m
     WHERE trunc(m.logoff_datum) <= trunc(cleanBefore.delete_before);

  DELETE FROM meeting_t m
  WHERE trunc(m.logoff_datum) <= trunc(cleanBefore.delete_before);

END cleanBefore;
```

This would avoid the context switches when looping over cursor records, and mean much fewer DML statements are issued. You may wish to consider locking the tables before issuing the deletes, so the whole procedure is processed atomically.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use **`ON DELETE CASCADE`** option :

```
SQL> drop table comm;
SQL> DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE;
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee
  2  (employee_id   NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL
  3  ,employee_name VARCHAR2(500)   NOT NULL
  4  ,salary        NUMBER(20)      NOT NULL
  5  ,department    VARCHAR2(300)   NOT NULL
  6  ,CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
  7  );
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE comm
  2  (emp_id             NUMBER(10)
  3  ,commission_percent NUMBER(20)
  4  ,CONSTRAINT fk_employee
  5   FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
  6   REFERENCES employee(employee_id)
  7   ON DELETE CASCADE
  8  );
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2  VALUES (101,'Emp A',10000,'Sales');
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2  VALUES (102,'Emp B',20000,'IT');
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2  VALUES (103,'Emp C',28000,'IT');
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO employee
  2  VALUES (104,'Emp D',30000,'Support');
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
  2  VALUES (105,'Emp E',32000,'Sales');
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO comm
  2  VALUES (102,20);
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO comm
  2  VALUES (103,20);
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO comm
  2  VALUES (104,NULL);
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO COMM
  2  VALUES (105,10);
SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM employee;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                      SALARY DEPARTMENT
----------- ------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
        101 Emp A                               10000 Sales
        102 Emp B                               20000 IT
        103 Emp C                               28000 IT
        104 Emp D                               30000 Support
        105 Emp E                               32000 Sales
SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM comm;

    EMP_ID COMMISSION_PERCENT
---------- ------------------
       102                 20
       103                 20
       104
       105                 10
SQL>
SQL> DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE
  2  WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 105;
SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM employee;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                      SALARY DEPARTMENT
----------- ------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
        101 Emp A                               10000 Sales
        102 Emp B                               20000 IT
        103 Emp C                               28000 IT
        104 Emp D                               30000 Support
SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM COMM;

    EMP_ID COMMISSION_PERCENT
---------- ------------------
       102                 20
       103                 20
       104
SQL>
```

**Update to below comment :**

```
SQL> SELECT *
      2  FROM employee;

    EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                      SALARY DEPARTMENT
    ----------- ------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
            101 Emp A                               10000 Sales
            102 Emp B                               20000 IT
            103 Emp C                               28000 IT
            104 Emp D                               30000 Support
            105 Emp E                               32000 Sales
    SQL>
    SQL> SELECT *
      2  FROM comm;

        EMP_ID COMMISSION_PERCENT
    ---------- ------------------
           102                 20
           103                 20
           104
           105                 10
    SQL>

SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN
  3    (SELECT TABLE_NAME
  4    FROM all_constraints
  5    WHERE r_constraint_name IN
  6      (SELECT constraint_name FROM all_constraints WHERE TABLE_NAME='EMPLOYEE'
  7      )
  8    )
  9    LOOP
 10      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from '||i.TABLE_NAME||' where emp_id = 101';
 11    END LOOP;
 12    DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 101;
 13  END;
 14  /
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME                      SALARY DEPARTMENT
----------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------
        102 Emp B                               20000 IT
        103 Emp C                               28000 IT
        104 Emp D                               30000 Support
SQL> SELECT * FROM COMM;

    EMP_ID COMMISSION_PERCENT
---------- ------------------
       102                 20
       103                 20
       104
SQL>
```

Comment: Tables can not be changed.

Comment: See my update, I have used `all_constraints` to avoid any hardcode and effort to find the dependent tables manually.

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to what you did, but using collections, so that I can minimize the number of Context Switches.

Also assuming that you have all the required Indices

```
CREATE TABLE meeting_t
(
meeting_id  NUMBER (10) ,
create_date DATE ,
 CONSTRAINT meeting_pk PRIMARY KEY (meeting_id)
);

CREATE TABLE prog_call
( prog_call_id NUMBER(10) ,
  meeting_id NUMBER(10),
  CONSTRAINT prog_call_pk PRIMARY KEY (prog_call_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_meeting_prog
    FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id)
    REFERENCES meeting_t(meeting_id)
);

CREATE TABLE lock_t
( lock_id NUMBER(10) ,
  prog_call_id NUMBER(10),
  CONSTRAINT lock_pk PRIMARY KEY (lock_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_prog_lock
    FOREIGN KEY (prog_call_id)
    REFERENCES prog_call(prog_call_id)
);


CREATE INDEX meeting_crt_dt ON meeting_t(create_date);

CREATE INDEX prog_call_meeting_idx ON prog_call(meeting_id);

CREATE INDEX lock_prog_call ON lock_t(prog_call_id);

SELECT     ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1000, 10000))
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;


INSERT INTO meeting_t
   SELECT object_id, created
     FROM dba_objects
    WHERE ROWNUM < 2000;

INSERT INTO prog_call
   SELECT object_id + object_id, object_id
     FROM dba_objects
    WHERE object_id IN (SELECT meeting_id
                          FROM meeting_t) AND ROWNUM < 2000;

INSERT INTO lock_t
   SELECT prog_call_id + prog_call_id, prog_call_id
     FROM prog_call;

COMMIT ;

SELECT *
  FROM meeting_t m, prog_call p, lock_t l
 WHERE m.meeting_id = p.meeting_id AND p.prog_call_id = l.prog_call_id
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE typ_num_tbl  IS TABLE OF NUMBER (10);

SELECT min(create_date), max(create_date) FROM meeting_t ;
```

Here is the procedure -

```
    PROCEDURE cleanbefore (p_delete_before DATE)
    IS
       -- meeting_t m, prog_call p, lock_t l
       CURSOR c_m
       IS
          SELECT m.meeting_id
            FROM meeting_t m
           WHERE m.create_date < p_delete_before;

       tbl_meeting_ids   typ_num_tbl := typ_num_tbl ();

       CURSOR c_p
       IS
          SELECT p.prog_call_id
            FROM prog_call p
           WHERE p.meeting_id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                                    FROM TABLE (tbl_meeting_ids));

       tbl_prog_ids      typ_num_tbl := typ_num_tbl ();
       n_limit           NUMBER (3)  := 500;
    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Start');

       OPEN c_m;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('10');

       -- meetings
       LOOP
          EXIT WHEN c_m%NOTFOUND;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('20');

          FETCH c_m
          BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_meeting_ids LIMIT n_limit;

          IF tbl_meeting_ids.COUNT > 0
          THEN
             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   '30 - tbl_meeting_ids.count:'
                                   || tbl_meeting_ids.COUNT
                                  );

             -- programs
             OPEN c_p;

             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('40');

             LOOP
                EXIT WHEN c_p%NOTFOUND;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('50');

                FETCH c_p
                BULK COLLECT INTO tbl_prog_ids LIMIT n_limit;

                IF tbl_prog_ids.COUNT > 0
                THEN
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   '60 - tbl_prog_ids.count:'
                                         || tbl_prog_ids.COUNT
                                        );

                   DELETE FROM lock_t l
                         WHERE l.prog_call_id IN (
                                   SELECT COLUMN_VALUE p_id
                                     FROM TABLE (CAST (tbl_prog_ids AS typ_num_tbl)
                                                ));

                   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('70  Deleted:' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

                   DELETE FROM prog_call p
                         WHERE p.meeting_id IN (
                                  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE m_id
                                    FROM TABLE
                                             (CAST (tbl_meeting_ids AS typ_num_tbl)
                                             ));

                   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('80 Deleted:' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

                   DELETE FROM meeting_t m
                         WHERE m.meeting_id IN (
                                  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE m_id
                                    FROM TABLE
                                             (CAST (tbl_meeting_ids AS typ_num_tbl)
                                             ));

                   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('81 Deleted:' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
                END IF;

                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('90');
             END LOOP;

             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('100');

             -- << end loop programs >>
             CLOSE c_p;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('110');
      END IF;
      -- COMMIT; -- COMMIT here if you dont care about ALL DELETE in ONE GO
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('120');

   -- << end loop meetings >>
   CLOSE c_m;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('130');
   tbl_meeting_ids.DELETE;
   tbl_prog_ids.DELETE;
   COMMIT;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('End');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      tbl_meeting_ids.DELETE;
      tbl_prog_ids.DELETE;

      IF c_m%ISOPEN
      THEN
         CLOSE c_m;
      END IF;

      IF c_p%ISOPEN
      THEN
         CLOSE c_p;
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
END;
```